# (DES) What is the probability that two keys (k1, k2) produce the same ciphertext given the same plaintext?

Tags: encryption, des

Basically, I need to find the probability that DES(p, k1) = DES(p, k2) = c

My guess is that probability = 1 / 2^64 since that's the total number of possible outputs, but honestly I have no clue about crypto. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Welcome to [cryptography.se]. Could you provide the origin of this question?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you mean. There are $2^{56}$ different DES keys and so if $k_1$ and $k_2$ are both chosen uniformly and independently at random, then there is a $2^{-56}$ chance that they are the same key in which case $\mathrm{DES}(p,k_1)=\mathrm{DES}(p,k_2)$ independently of the choice of $p$. (With non-causal cases being a second-order effect).

If on the other hand $k_1$ and $k_2$ are distinct and $p$ is chosen uniformly at random then @kodlu's analysis holds.

However, if we choose distinct $k_1$ and $k_2$ then ask for the probability that there exists some $p$ such that $\mathrm{DES}(p,k_1)=\mathrm{DES}(p,k_2)$ is the probability that $\pi_{k_1}^{-1}(\pi_{k_2}(x))$ is not a [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) which is roughly $(1-1/e)$ (assuming that the DES operation is indistinguishable from a random permutation).

Answer (score 3):

Let $DES(p,k)$ be modeled by the pseudorandom permutation $\pi_{k}:\{0,1\}^{64}\rightarrow \{0,1\}^{64}.$ Then
$$
DES(p,k_1)=DES(p,k_2) \Leftrightarrow \pi_{k_2}^{-1}(\pi_{k_1}(p))=p.
$$
Since $\pi_{k_2}^{-1}(\pi_{k_1}(\cdot))$ is itself a pseudorandom permutation. The probability that a given point $p$ is fixed by this permutation is $1/2^{64}$ which is the ratio $(n-1)!/n!$ with $n=2^{64}$ since there are $(n-1)!$ permutations on $n$ points which fix a given point.